# Fetch IP address dynamically when app is started

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app, it hits an external server and gets required data. But I'm configuring the IP address in the application itself i.e, I'm hard coding the IP. Is there any alternative where the app fetches IP address dynamically from database? Since it's really difficult to configure IP address every now and then.

Comment: What's wrong with DNS? Or by IP you refer to host name?

Comment: even if you wre to get the ip from a db perhaps on the server u will need one more ip to make a req for an ip ? isnt it ? If its local, neway you will have to change the db some point in time if the ip changes

Comment: make your ip a constant value :)